# Count off to split into teams

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, grammaticality

In school group projects or sports, how do you command the students/players to count off 1-2-1-2-1-2 or 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3 etc. to split into two or three (or more) teams, respectively?

I gather you do use the verb "to count off," but I couldn't find reliable quotes or sources on how to form a command and specify the number to count to.

I did found single quotes with these options:
"Count off by 2s!"
"Count off one through three!"

How do these sound? Can you say "Count off one through two!" also? Is there a succinct, idiomatic and systematic way to formulate this? Along the lines of "Let's ____!"

Thanks!

Comment: Here's where tautology works in our favor: *Count off by 3s: 1, 2, 3, 1.*

Comment: 'Count off' appears in various dictionaries; the [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+off) explanation is perhaps the most explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Various dictionaries give this expression. [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+off) gives perhaps the clearest explanation of the sense used here (with several other senses), with an example sentence:

> **count off**
>
> 1. To count in turn, as when dividing a group of people into smaller groups. A noun or pronoun can be used between "count" and "off."
>
> - *OK, kids, count off one through five so that we can make five groups.*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/count-off) similarly has:

> **count off** [often used imperatively, as in the army]: to count aloud by turns, as to arrange positions within a group of persons;
> divide or become divided into groups
>
> - *Close up ranks and count off from the left by threes*

and the [Mcgraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms ...](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+off):

**count off** [for a series of people, one by one]: to say aloud the next number in a fixed sequence.

- *The soldiers counted off by threes* [One, two, three / one. two, three / ...].
- The sergeant told them to count off.

The essence is that this is modular (clock) arithmetic; everyone is assigned to a subset (residue class 0, 1, 2 in modulo 3, for instance) according to the number they say out, and equal (as near as possible) sets are produced.

Answer (score 0):

When I was less tall than I am now, we used to *do potatoes*. Each child held out two fists, and someone counted round them...one potato, two potato, three potato, four, five potato, six potato, seven potato, more. The fist counted more would then be withdrawn, and the process repeated until someone had no fists out, and they would be selected. For a team, repeat until the desired number had been thus chosen.